# Sharing html files in Hot Towel Template similar to partial views in MVC application

Tags: html, file, knockout.js, sharing, hottowel

I am using Hot Towel template with knockout data binding. I have certain HTML that I know is going to be used at several places in my application. Is it possible to share my HTML files similar to using partial views in an MVC application ?
Also, the windows sharing the html files will be open simultaneously. Both will be bound to same observables. Will this cause a problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Knockout Compose binding provided by Durandal.  You will need to provide more code if you want additional help with the solution.  You can bind two views or as much HTML as you want to as many observables as you want without problems.

```
<div data-bind="with: myData">
    <!-- ko compose: 'views/myDependentView' -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```